# @Async annotation in SpringBoot not saving Data to DB

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a scenario in my project where I need to develop a asynchronous service which will perform some DB update operation from Spring Boot.I am aware that `@Async` always spawn a new thread.So,I am taking following actions:

I have created two separate Service classes.

**First Service class** [say Service Class A]

```
@Async
@Override
public Future<MyResponseModel> myMethodForApproval(parameterList) {
    MyResponseModel myResponseModel= new MyResponseModel();
    serviceClassB.performApproval(parameterList); 
    myResponseModel.setStatus("Success");
    myResponseModel.setMessage("Approval process initiated successfully");
    return new AsyncResult<MyResponseModel>(myResponseModel);
}
```

**In Second service class** [Say Service Class B, actual business logic is written]

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = { Throwable.class })
public void performApproval(parameterList) {
  //all the business logic checking.
  repoLayer.saveAll(myEntities);
```

}

In controller Layer:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/approveProcess", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { "application/json" })
public ResponseEntity<MyResponseModel> approveProcess(@RequestBody parameterList) {
    serviceClassA.myMethodForApproval(parameterList);
}
```

Now exception I am getting

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: no transaction is in progress; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
```

Comment: Is the exception thrown at the `repoLayer.saveAll` call, or at what line?

Comment: @David Conrad,yes exception is getting thrown at the repoLayer.saveAll

Comment: Have you enabled asynchronous processing by adding @EnableAsync to your configuration class? [source](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async) . Also, the new thread will by default open a new db connection, so propagation = REQUIRES_NEW is redundant, unless this method is called from non Async methods as well.

Comment: yes @EnableAsync is added in project